# How to fix "line 28: CHOOSE:: command not found"

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, opensuse

I am trying to build a rpm package using OBS. However, I get the following error when running `osc build`:

```
    [    4s] Executing(%check): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.KwrQs4
    [    4s] + umask 022
    [    4s] + cd /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD
    [    4s] + cd pytz-2021.1
    [    4s] + CHOOSE:
    [    4s] /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.KwrQs4: line 28: CHOOSE:: command not found
    [    4s] error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.KwrQs4 (%check)
    [    4s] 
    [    4s] 
    [    4s] RPM build errors:
    [    4s]     Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.KwrQs4 (%check)
    [    4s] 
    [    4s] meteor failed "build python-pytz.spec" at Thu Feb 11 14:37:40 UTC 2021.
    [    4s]
```

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out:
In the check section it says
`CHOOSE pytest OR pyunittest -v` when generating the spec file using `py2pack`- should have read that. Choosing either pytest or pyuinttest works fine.

Answer (score 0):

How do you get to this point? What is the full content of `%check` section? Why you did not use `pyp2rpm pytz` which generates a nice and working spec file?

I hope that at least one of these questions actually answers your question. :)

Comment: Thank you! Analyzing the file and thinking a bit about it's content helped.